# Qt 5.1 for Android error with ndk and mingw32-make

Tags: android-ndk, makefile, mingw, qt5

I’v downloaded Qt for Android windows 8 32 bit, The Android **SDK**, The Android **NDK**, **apache-ant**-1.9.2 and **jdk**-7u25. (everything **32** bit). 
Extracted and installed and set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the JDK install directory path.

QtCreator seems to recognize everything, everything is good with desktop, but when I try to build for **Android** I get this error :
(error: error: Android\android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/: No such file or directory).

I had deleted the android-ndk-r8e and extracted it again, and got the same error.

I also  added to system variable path the path of mingw32-make.exe file.

**Here is the output for the error**:

```
16:49:51: Running steps for project animatedtiles...
16:49:51: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
16:49:51: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/ -Wl,-soname,libanimatedtiles.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -o libanimatedtiles.so main.obj qrc_animatedtiles.obj   -LC:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Android\android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/libs/armeabi-v7a -LC:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Android\android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm//usr/lib -lgnustl_shared -lsupc++ -llog -lz -lm -ldl -lc -lgcc -LC:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\\5.1.0\android_armv7\lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGLESv2 
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: Files: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: (x86)\Android\android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/: No such file or directory
makefile:185: recipe for target 'libanimatedtiles.so' failed
mingw32-make: *** [libanimatedtiles.so] Error 1
16:49:53: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project animatedtiles (kit: Android for arm (GCC 4.4.3, Qt 5.1.0))
When executing step 'Make'
16:49:53: Elapsed time: 00:02.
```

Here are two image for the android configuration and the project configuration:
[image: error with the image]

[image]

***Thanks***

Answer (score 0):

It appears to barf on your "--sysroot=" option, it looks like it doesn't like the spaces in the sysroot path you supplied (maybe it needs quotes?).  I'm not an expert, but I don't think you need a --sysroot option in this case.  I have been able to at least compile and deploy Android apk's to a device with a blank sysroot.  I can set sysroot from QtCreator from Tools/Options... "Build and Run"/Kits.